# Multiple- or single-entry for Schengen visa if I am travelling to multiple countries

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens

My parents and I are travelling to Europe in May. Below is our itinerary. Will we require a single- or a multiple-entry visa? We have Indian passports.

My itinerary:

- Italy: 7th to 15th May
- Czech: 15th to 19th May
- Belgium: 19th to 22nd May
- Netherlands: 22nd to 26th May

Parents:
Italy: 7th to 15th May

Since I am visiting multiple countries, would I require a single-entry visa or a multiple-entry visa? From what I understand, we would require a single-entry, since I am not exiting the Schengen area during my trip.

Comment: Your understanding is corect.

Answer (score 1):

You require a single entry visa, since as your itinerary suggests, you will not be leaving the Schengen zone. Its not something you need to worry about. The consulate decides on the no of entries and duration of your visa depending on your profile (for e.g. past travel history) and itinerary.

Comment: If any travel between Schengen countries involves a flight (or other transit) through another non-Schengen country, a single-entry visa will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You require a single-entry visa from the **Italian** embassy/consulate. However, if you have positive peripatetic history, they may grant a multi-entry visa anyway, which is not a cause for concern.

Comment: If any travel between Schengen countries involves a flight (or other transit) through another non-Schengen country, a single-entry visa will not be sufficient.

Comment: @phoog Based on the Q though I assume it doesn't, but correct!

Comment: I realize the question doesn't imply such a transit, but it seems so easy to overlook that I think it ought to be mentioned whenever possible

Comment: @phoog,@coke - I have booked all direct flights, so there is no stop over/transit at any non Schengen country.

Comment: @Karishma All good then!